# How important is RPC_S_UUID_LOCAL_ONLY when creating Sequential Guids?

Tags: c#, sql, guid

I copies the following codesnipped from http://www.dbdelta.com/improving-uniqueidentifier-performance/ to create sequential Guids:

```
private static Guid NewSequentialGuid()
        {
            const int S_OK = 0;
            const int RPC_S_UUID_LOCAL_ONLY = 1824;

            Guid oldGuid = Guid.Empty;

            int result = UuidCreateSequential(ref oldGuid);
            if (result != S_OK && result != RPC_S_UUID_LOCAL_ONLY)
            {
                throw new ExternalException("UuidCreateSequential call failed", result);
            }

            byte[] oldGuidBytes = oldGuid.ToByteArray();
            byte[] newGuidBytes = new byte[16];
            oldGuidBytes.CopyTo(newGuidBytes, 0);

            // swap low timestamp bytes (0-3)
            newGuidBytes[0] = oldGuidBytes[3];
            newGuidBytes[1] = oldGuidBytes[2];
            newGuidBytes[2] = oldGuidBytes[1];
            newGuidBytes[3] = oldGuidBytes[0];

            // swap middle timestamp bytes (4-5)
            newGuidBytes[4] = oldGuidBytes[5];
            newGuidBytes[5] = oldGuidBytes[4];

            // swap high timestamp bytes (6-7)
            newGuidBytes[6] = oldGuidBytes[7];
            newGuidBytes[7] = oldGuidBytes[6];

            //remaining 8 bytes are unchanged (8-15) 

            return new Guid(newGuidBytes);

        }
```

What confuses me, is the `&& result != RPC_S_UUID_LOCAL_ONLY` check. I don't understand why/when I should or shouldn't check for this value.

Can somebody please clarify? Can I just leave this check out or will I run into problems?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379322(v=vs.85).aspx) for the method? The remarks section does a decent job (IMO) of explaining why you may not want to rely on values produced with that success code.

Comment: Yes I read it, but this line here confuses me: "Computers with ethernet/token ring addresses generate UUIDs that are guaranteed to be globally unique" - Sounds like you WANT to use this check after all but I am not sure. EDIT: nvm, now I understood it. D'OH

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Damnien_The_Unbeliever for opening my eyes to the obvious.

Comment: this comment is unnecessary, please consider deleting it. This is a section for Answers